# Not able to get data from retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to pass login and register api in android. But I am getting response as 409 in return. I am not getting data from api. Retrofit 2 is used here

```
SignUpApi signupapi = Api_Config.getInstance3().getApiBuilder().create(SignUpApi.class);

        Call<SignUpApi.ResponseSignUp> call = signupapi.POSTDATA(UserName.getText().toString().trim(),
                Email.getText().toString().trim(),
                Password.getText().toString().trim(),
                Sex.getText().toString().trim(),
                Mobile.getText().toString().trim());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SignUpApi.ResponseSignUp>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SignUpApi.ResponseSignUp> call, Response<SignUpApi.ResponseSignUp> response) {
            CustomProgressDialog.getInstance().dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()){

                Log.e("Status is",response.body().getStatus().toString());

                if (response.body().getStatus() == 200){
                    CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,Constants.SuccessfullyRegistered);
                    CommonFunctions.getInstance().FinishActivityWithDelay(SignInActivity.this);
                }else if (response.body().getStatus() == 409){
                    CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,Constants.YouAreAlreadyRegistered);
                }else{
                    CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,response.body().getMsg());
                }
            } else {
                CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,Constants.SomethingWentWrong);
            }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SignUpApi.ResponseSignUp> call, Throwable t) {
                CustomProgressDialog.getInstance().dismiss();
                CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Below is my API configuration

```
public static Api_Config getInstance3()
{
    if (ourInstance == null){
        synchronized (Api_Config.class){
            if ( ourInstance == null )
                ourInstance = new Api_Config();
        }
    }
    ourInstance.config3();
    return ourInstance;
}

private void config3() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    String BASE_URL3 = LOGIN_AND_SIGNUP;
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL3)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
}
```

Below is my Api Class

```
public interface SignUpApi {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register.php")
Call<ResponseSignUp> POSTDATA(@Field("user_name")String username,
                              @Field("user_email")String email,
                              @Field("user_password")String password,
                              @Field("user_gender")String sex,
                              @Field("user_mobile")String mobile
                              );

public class ResponseSignUp
{


    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }


}
```

I am newbee to android and really confused why my code is not working. Looking for help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you note just answered your own question? If you're getting a `409` it means you already have an account and you can't register with those same credentials. Have you tried to pass different credentials in?

Comment: I had tried with many different credentials but the response is 409. @StuStirling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if your response was successfully it means you got a successful code (200...300). However, if you get a response 401, 409.. it means you got an error, **then** your response was not successfully. Put the error handle outside the `response.isSuccessful()` condition.

```
if (response.isSuccessful()){
        //Handle success response here
        Log.e("Status is",response.body().getStatus().toString());
        CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,Constants.SuccessfullyRegistered);
        CommonFunctions.getInstance().FinishActivityWithDelay(SignInActivity.this);
        } else {
         // Handle error response here, 401, 409...
              if (response.body().getStatus() == 409){
                    CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,Constants.YouAreAlreadyRegistered);
              }else{
                    CommonFunctions.getInstance().ShowSnackBar(SignInActivity.this,response.body().getMsg());
            }
        }
```

You can check this in the retrofit2 files.

```
/** Returns true if {@link #code()} is in the range [200..300). */
  public boolean isSuccessful() {
    return rawResponse.isSuccessful();
  }
```

**EDIT**
Depper explanation

I'll try to explain better. When you call retrofit using enqueue method like this: `call.enqueue()` you expect to get a Response or Failure from the server: `onResponse()` means you got a response and `onFailure()` means you failed to connect to the server, it could mean the server is broken or there is no internet connection.

If you got a `onResponse()` from the server it does not mean it was successful, it just means you got a response, therefore you need to check if this response was successful or not by using this condition

```
if (response.isSuccessful){
}
```

**What is a successful response?**

If you end up inside this condition `response.isSuccessful` it already means you got a successful response and this is a response with code between 200 and 300.

However, if you want to check if you got a 409 code. 409 code means that it was a unsuccessful response, then you need to check this outside the success condition.

```
if (response.isSuccessful){
    // You got a successful response, the code is from 200 to 300.
} else {
    // You got a unsuccessful response, handle the code 401, 405, 409 here.
}
```

Comment: I cant understand clearly. Can you please give me some example or edit my code and post it @Soon Santos

Comment: Thank you for your explanation that was helpful I clearly understood. But one thing i can't understand is why my code is not working? why I am not getting 200 as response. @Soon Santos

Comment: It seems alright, check if your BASE_URL and endpoint are correct. Also, you should make a call to the server using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) app before doing it in Android Studio to check if it is all right with the server and with your call. I would recommend you to watch [this playlist from future studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4XU8yPzSx0&list=PLpUMhvC6l7APq7y_FFfK-GEHvcUKqo6SC). It is 27 classes that will help you a lot while working with Retrofit.

Comment: After becoming pro in Retrofit, if your app has a lot of retrofit calls, I also would suggest you call retrofit in [this way](https://medium.com/@saquib3705/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-with-the-help-of-mvvm-dagger-livedata-and-rxjava2-in-67aebefe031d). This MVVM approach is good for avoiding leaks and problems while rotating the device.

Comment: Do you have your whole code on git? So I can check what is going on.

Comment: No.I don't know git integration. give me your mail ID I'll send you my code